# Azure Scheduler Certification error

Tags: c#, azure, ssl, scheduler, x509certificate2

I'm using new Azure Scheduler service and I have this issue.

I have one console application that works fine with this few code lines

```
var credentials = new CertificateCloudCredentials(subscriptionId, certificate);
var schedulerClient= new SchedulerManagementClient(credentials);
var jobCollAvailable = schedulerClient.JobCollections.CheckNameAvailability(cloudServiceName, jobCollectionName_NE);
```

I use the same code lines in a API service with service stack. 
When CheckNameAvailability method is called system throws this exception :

*Forbidden Error: The server failed to authenticate the request. Verify that the certificate is valid and is associated with this subscription.*

1. Since Friday everything worked also into the service. I had only changed the certificate with another one.
2. If I remove certificate from Azure the console app throws the same error( but in this case is correct). I have tried with more than one certificate for to be sure and console app has worked fine.
3. The Certificate loaded and used from Service has the same thumbprint that the console app one.

Thanks for your suggests

Comment: I have tried also with fiddler with the same certificate and rest call works fine.

Comment: It seems a knowledge issue . https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/897

Comment: This is Vivek from the Azure team. Sorry you are running into issues. Can you please let me know more about the 'API service in service stack' that you're referring to, above? Is it a web role?